# How is updating the indices buffer handled in gfx-rs?

Tags: graphics, rust

The only way I have found that accepts the indices buffer is:

```
let (vbuf, slice) = factory.create_vertex_buffer(&verts, &indices);
```

This creates a new buffer and I can't do it every frame.

I can update the vertex buffer with `encoder.update_buffer(&buf, &data, offset)`, but I don't know how to update indices buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the index buffer by using the `slice` that comes from creating the vertex buffer.

The slice has a public field, [`slice.buffer`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.18.2/gfx/struct.Slice.html) that represents the index buffer itself, although this is a [`gfx::IndexBuffer`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.18.2/gfx/enum.IndexBuffer.html), not a [`gfx::handle::Buffer`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.18.2/gfx/handle/struct.Buffer.html), which is required for the call to [`encoder.update_buffer(...)`](https://docs.rs/gfx/0.18.2/gfx/struct.Encoder.html#method.update_buffer).

In order to get the underlying buffer, match on the `IndexBuffer` to the type you created, as such:

```rust
match &slice.buffer {
    // On `Auto`, there is no index buffer
    gfx::IndexBuffer::Auto => ...,
    
    // On `Index16`, the indices are `u16`
    gfx::IndexBuffer::Index16(buffer) => ...,

    // On `Index32`, the indices are `u32`
    gfx::IndexBuffer::Index32(buffer) => ...,
}
```

Only one of these will match at runtime, depending on the index buffer you chose when creating the vertex buffer.

On the `Index16` and `Index32` cases, `buffer` will be a `gfx::handle::Buffer<R, T>`, where `T` is `u16` or `u32`.